# How to allow duplicate comments?

Tags: comments

i am working on an event that requires users to be able to comment, everyday on my blog for a period of them, i have been looking for the possible way to allow duplicate comments on my blog. please can anyone tell me how to enable duplicate comments

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');
```

Comment: It worked like a charm for me!!!
Added this line at the end of ```wp-includes/functions.php``` file and restarted the server.